# generic class with factory design in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, factory-pattern

May i know why below code line not work, it output

> Type 'instanceA' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'instanceA' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'.

```
interface A {}

class instanceA implements A {}

type instanceComponent = (typeof instanceA);

class factory<T extends A = A> {
    private _methods : instanceComponent[] = [instanceA];
    private _components: {[key:string] : T } = {};
    constructor() 
    {
    }
    createInstance(name: string ) : T
    {
        if(typeof this._components[name] != "undefined")
        {
           return new this._methods[0](); //error warning in this line
        }
        throw new Error(`Instance [${name}] not supported.`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your factory can be instantiated with `T = anotherInstanceA`.

Comment: so how to build such generic factory? assume i need T to return the interface to the caller, so that i can call the interface method

Answer (score 0):

yes, so the solution will be

```
interface A { code :string }

interface B extends A {}

class instanceA implements A {
    static NAME : string = "A";
    code = instanceA.NAME;
}
class instanceB implements B {
    static NAME : string = "B";
    code = instanceB.NAME;
}
type instanceComponent = (typeof instanceA)|(typeof instanceB);

class factory<T extends A> {
    private _methods : (instanceComponent)[] = [instanceA, instanceB];
    private _components: {[key:string] : T } = {};
    constructor() 
    {
    }
    createInstance(name: string ) : T
    {
        if(typeof this._components[name] == undefined)
        {
            const obj  = this._methods.find(e => e.NAME === name);
            if(obj != undefined)
            {
                const s = new obj();
                this._components[s.code] = s as T;
            }
            throw new Error("errr");
        }
        return this._components[name];
    }
}
```

Comment: Empty interfaces are almost always a bad idea, since they are structurally compatible with anything.

Comment: it just for demo purpose, my point is how to make a factory design that can create. generic class which all of them has the same base class, but some how i can call the interface method by defining what interface when using factory

Comment: @Cerberus do you understand what i mean